# Store Procedure: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, devexpress

I get an error:
`Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

My store procedure:

```
USE [DEMO]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[demo] @from_day varchar(20), @to_day varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
select db.*
from db
where
convert(date,db.DateUse,103) between convert(date, @from_day,103) and convert(date, @to_day,103)

END
```

I use ASPxDateEdit (DevExpress) with 2 param:

```
<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="from_day" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="from_day" 
                        EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"   Width="100px"  
                        Theme="Aqua"  > 
</dx:ASPxDateEdit>

<dx:ASPxDateEdit ID="to_day" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="to_day" 
                         EditFormat="Custom" EditFormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" Width="100px" 
                         Theme="Aqua"> 
</dx:ASPxDateEdit>
```

I use SelectParameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DEMOConn %>" SelectCommand="demo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
           <SelectParameters>
               <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="from_day" Name="from_day" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
               <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="to_day" Name="to_day" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
           </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I cannot  fix this error.

Comment: This is Because `convert(date, @from_day,103) and convert(date, @to_day,103)`, Can You Please show us, how you are passing the parameter to SP??

Comment: I use SelectParameters:

<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="from_day" Name="from_day" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="to_day" Name="to_day" PropertyName="Value" Type="String" />

Comment: your Query is Wrong,
you missed table name, from etc etc
 
`Select * from table_Name Where date Between dat1 and dat2`

Comment: Sorry, because I edit wrong. 
I edited question.

Comment: Change Type="DateTime", 
 <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="from_day" Name="from_day" PropertyName="Value" Type="DateTime" />

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
It run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string to a datetime parameter in your SP. Either change the data type in your ControlParameters to DateTime or convert the string in your SP to a datetime value. Personally I'd change the ControlPatameters. Hope this helps